# Why doesn't control pass back the main function after the if condition of the recursion failed?

Tags: c, recursion

I'm on chapter 9 of *C Primer Plus* where the author introduced the thing called recursion. I'm confused about the output of the sample program he presented. Need some help from your guys.

Below is the code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void up_and_down(int);
 int main(void)
 {
    up_and_down(1);
    return 0;
 }
 void up_and_down(int n)
 {
    printf("Level %d: n location %p\n", n, &n); // 1
    if (n < 4)
       up_and_down(n+1);
    printf("LEVEL %d: n location %p\n", n, &n); // 2
 }
```

Here is the output

1. Level 1: n location 0x0012ff48
2. Level 2: n location 0x0012ff3c
3. Level 3: n location 0x0012ff30
4. Level 4: n location 0x0012ff24
5. LEVEL 4: n location 0x0012ff24
6. LEVEL 3: n location 0x0012ff30
7. LEVEL 2: n location 0x0012ff3c
8. LEVEL 1: n location 0x0012ff48

No problem up till Level 4 where n = 4. At this point, the if statement fails and then the second printf function is executed. After the second printf print out `Level 4: n location 0x0012ff24`, shouldn't the control pass back to `return 0` in the main function? Why does the second printf continue to printf out the other three n variables and specifically in the backward direction.

The author explains that it's becasue

> control
> passes back to the function that called it (the Level 3 call). The last statement executed in the
> Level 3 call was the call to Level 4 in the if statement. Therefore, Level 3 resumes with the
> following statement, which is print statement #2. This causes LEVEL 3 to be printed. Then
> Level3 ends, passing control to Level 2, which prints LEVEL 2, and so on.

I understand each word he said, but together forming those sentences, I have no idea what he's talking about at all.

Why does the second printf continue to print 3,2 and 1? And particularly in that order. Does the second printf means to print out all the n variables? What's the logic behind the way the second printf behaves.

Comment: There are multiple `up_and_down` calls on the call stack at the same time, each with different values of `n`.

Comment: The first thing I see is that each call to `up_and_down` is going to call `printf` twice.  So if their are four recursive calls, right away I expect to see eight lines printed.

Answer (score 3):

> shouldn't the control pass back to return 0 in the main function?

No, it shouldn't. Let me try to, well, convince you with an analogy.

Suppose you had four functions: `up_and_down_1()`, `up_and_down_2()`, `up_and_down_3()` and `up_and_down_4()`, each calling the next one inside.

Now if I'm in the body of `up_and_down_1()`, and I call `up_and_down_2()`, and that function concludes (never mind what it does) - control returns to the next line in `up_and_down_1()` after the call to `up_and_down_2()`. That's how functions call work in C (see also [here](http://%60https://abrickshort.wordpress.com/2005/04/10/how-function-calls-work/) for the low-level nitty-gritty).

Well, it's the same situation with the recursive calls to `up_and_down()`. It doesn't matter that the function being called happens to be the same function. The machine remembers that control needs to return to a certain line in `up_and_down()`, with the local variables set the way they were before the call - and that is not affected by the fact that there's an inner call to the same function. The inner call is its own context, has its own pass of control within the code of `up_and_down()`, and doesn't affect the outer call.

I can also suggest a short illustration video about how this works on typical machines:

[What Are The Call Stack And Stack Frames In Recursive Programming?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmQK7FfYggs)

Comment: That's a very useful explanation. Thank you so much. And could you check my understanding here? So, right after the 2nd printf print out Level 4, ````up_and_down(4)```` function reaches the end. Then, the 2nd printf should return to the function who called it, specifically, return to the **last line** of that calling function, which is ````up_and_down(3)````. Within this function, n = 3, and the **last line** is the **2nd printf**, thus the output would be  _LEVEL 3: n location 0x0012ff30_ .

Comment: And again, as the 2nd printf in ````up_and down(3)```` gets executed, it's going to return to the last line of its calling function. Who called````up_and down(3)```` ? ````up_and down(2)````. And this process continues until the 2nd printf in ````up_and down(1)```` is executed. And from there, the 2nd printf will finally return to the main function, because it was the main function that called ````up_and down(1)```` . Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Because recursion is not special, and when a function returns (any function; including recursive function calls), execution picks up where it left off before the function was called. This means that when you're inside of the third-level, it makes a recursive call to the fourth-level. When the fourth-level call returns, execution goes back to where it was before the recursive function was called: the third level.

Forget about recursion for a second. Say you have a custom function of yours that contains a call to `printf`, and that custom function is called from within `main`. When `printf` returns, where does execution resume to? `main`, or inside your custom function where it left off? The latter. Your function needs to finish executing the code after the `printf` call, and then when it's finished execution returns back to `main`. It's the same with recursive functions.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. Can you check if I understand this correclty? So, right after the 2nd printf print out Level 4, up_and_down(4) function reaches the end. Then, the 2nd printf should return to the function who called it, specifically, return to the last line of that calling function, which is up_and_down(3). Within this function, n = 3, and the last line is the 2nd printf, thus the output would be LEVEL 3: n location 0x0012ff30 .

Comment: And again, as the 2nd printf in up_and down(3) gets executed, it's going to return to the last line of its calling function. Who calledup_and down(3) ? up_and down(2). And this process continues until the 2nd printf in up_and down(1) is executed. And from there, the 2nd printf will finally return to the main function, because it was the main function that called up_and down(1) . Am I right?

Comment: @Sherri In your code, `printf` returns to the function that called it (`up_and_down`), then `up_and_down` returns to the function that called it. That function is either `up_and_down` (if the current function call is one of the deeper recursive calls), or `main` (if the current function call is the initial one). Remember that when your code does `up_and_down(3)`, the memory associated with the `up_and_down(2)` function call still exists. That function call is still hanging around taking up space on the stack so it can pick up where it left off when the function it called is finished.

Comment: so ````printf```` does not return to a specific line of the function that called it ( ````up_and_down````) ? I thought ````printf```` is going to return to the last line of the calling function, that is the second ````printf```` and control resume from there, printing out _LEVEL 3_ . When you say return, what is it really happening there?

Answer (score 2):

Its explained unneccessarily complicated. When you call a function you execute whatever code is in there. When a function calls another function it executes the code and then combes back to where it was. You can, for the sake of this example, imagine it like pasting the contents with the args replaced, so up_and_down(1) becomes:

```c
printf("Level %d: n location %p\n", n, &n); // n = 1
if (n < 4) { // n = 1
    printf("Level %d: n location %p\n", n, &n); // n = 2
    if (n < 4) // n = 2
       ... paste again with n = 3
    printf("LEVEL %d: n location %p\n", n, &n); // n = 2
}
printf("LEVEL %d: n location %p\n", n, &n); // n = 1
```

That very basically is:

```c
print("enter 1")
if (...)
  print("enter 2")
  if (...)
    print("enter 3")
    if (...)
      print("enter 4")
      // if evaluates to false here, so we dont go deeper
      print("exit 4")
    print("exit 3")
  print("exit 2")
print("exit 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

lets start from  n=1  , it prints the first printf , then it goes inside the condition and calls the same function again,  when  that function finishs its job the program will  move on to the next line which is the second printf, so really the second printf isnt skipped, its just waiting for the function call to finish,  this happens in n=2 and n=3 etc,

Answer (score 0):

Each function call "blocks" until the invoked function returns.

Level 1 will call Level 2 before Level 1 reaches the second `printf`. However, Level 2 will call Level 3 before it reaches the second `printf` and finally returns.

This will continue for all levels until we reach level 4. At Level 4, the if statement evaluates to `false`, so `up_and_down(n+1)` is never reached and level 5 will thus never be a thing.

Therefore, Level 4 is the first Level to reach its implicit `return`. Level 4 held up Level 3, so with Level 4 out of the way, Level 3 can continue execution and the next instruction in line is `printf("LEVEL %d......<something>", n, &n);` where `n = 3`. After that, Level 3 reaches its `return` and unblocks Level 2, and so on.

Recursion works like a stack, not a queue.

```
void up_and_down(int n)
{
    printf("Level %d: n location %p\n", n, &n); // 1
    if (n < 4)
       up_and_down(n+1);
    printf("LEVEL %d: n location %p\n", n, &n); // 2
    return;  // Return and unblock the function level that invoked this level, which is level n - 1
}
```

If you still don't understand recursion, read this again.